# How to use $anchorScroll for modals in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, anchor-scroll

I am working on Angular JS in which I have one modal window. It has one scrollbar and some hidden elements. Those hidden elements get visible only when user clicks on certain button. So I want when user clicks on that button then scrollbar should move automatically bottom of the popup window.
For that, I am taking help of $anchorScroll service of angular JS. The problem is, this service is scrolling the main page instead of popup window.

Below is my controller code:

```
angular.module('appControllers').controller('ApplicationCtrl',
 ['$scope', '$anchorScroll', '$location','$timeout', 'socket', '$compile', '$window',
 'ModalService', 'MetricService', 'UtilService',
  function($scope, $anchorScroll, $location, DeploymentManagerService,
    $timeout, socket, $compile, $window, ModalService, MetricService, UtilService) {

$scope.showStageSummary:function(arg){

               if($("#"+arg.name).hasClass("hidden")){
                 $("#"+arg.name).removeClass("hidden");
                 gotoAnchor(50);
               }else{
                $("#"+arg.name).addClass("hidden");
              }
            }

$scope.gotoAnchor = function(x) {
            var newHash = 'anchor' + x;
            if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
              $location.hash('anchor' + x);
            } else {
              $anchorScroll();
            }
        };
});
```

I want this automatic scrolling to be applied on my modal window. How can I do that?